# Leaving Schengen when having two permits in EU for non-eu people

Tags: resident-permit, schengen

I have two work permits in EU ( Austria , Czech Republic)
I want to leave Schengen from (Prague , Czech Republic), I will come back to (Prague , Czech Republic) and present my passport + Czech Permit.

Should I have to do something regarding the Austrian Permit, I mean: will I be registered that I entered Schengen again in Austrian System?

What I have to do if not?

Answer (score 1):

There is no Schengen-wide system for electronically recording routine entries and exits. The only system in place is passport stamps. Therefore, whether you present your Czech or Austrian residence permit is of no consequence. While the Czech Republic may record your information electronically, this information will not be available to Austria. You don't need to have your entry to Schengen "registered" with any Austrian authority.